# Need help identifying Mystery plant

Tags: identification, houseplants

This pot holder has had a money plant growing in it for a few years. Recently though, another plant suddenly started growing...possibly a seed or two were carried by the wind and fell into this planter.

I have tried to find photos of similar plants online with descriptions/explanations provided but, unfortunately, have not found anything to help identify this usurping plant.

I am wondering if I should get rid of it, if it is a weed. If not, would very much like to know what plant it is.

[image: Plant with broad serrated leaves and a money plant]

Answer (score 2):

I think that might be a Mother of Thousands plant (Devil's backbone).  If it is, you will be in for a treat as each of the tips grows new tiny plantlets.